# How can I speed up finding matching values in two lists?

Tags: python

I am trying to find positions in a genome that are significant, from a list of possible locations.

I first identify the possible genome sites and store these in a list, then create another list with the significant sites, and loop through this checking if each significant site is in the list of possible sites.

The software which generates the significant sites and the possible locations can give positions which differ by up to about 3 positions so I check a range of positions +/- 3 from any significant site.

What I have written works, but only for small subsections of the genome, otherwise it takes hours and I'm wondering if there is a faster way of doing this?

```
with open(genome) as g:
    seq = g.readlines()
    for l in range(len(seq)):
        if (l % 2 == 0):
            sequence = seq[l+1]
            dam_matches = re.finditer(dam, sequence)
            dam_positions = [match.start()
                             for match in dam_matches]
            
            for position in dam_positions:
                dam_list.append(position)


modified_dam=[]


for site in significant_sites:
    motif_range_min = int(site) - 3
    motif_range_max = int(site) + 3
    for value in range(motif_range_min, motif_range_max):
        if value in dam_list:
            if value not in modified_dam:
                modified_dam.append(value)
```

Comment: An obvious optimization would be to replace list membership tests by set membership tests.

Comment: Can you cut down the example to code to the problem at hand? Your problem is that you have two lists, and you want to find matches of elements of these two lists? All the file reading and string handling is not part of the problem, I presume? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Usually boiling down a problem to its essential core is already half of the solution.

Comment: Secondly, there are libraries for processing such data, which are probably already optimized.

Comment: This question might be more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Sid, Thanks I didn't know about codereview